# Generic XUnit C# .NET Core API Tests with different models

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, crud, xunit

I would like to write a generic XUnit test for my CRUD API methods. However, I am not sure how to implement this with different models.

I wanted to use the following code:

```
public class BaseControllerTests<TModel> : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Program>>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;
    private List<string> _modelIds = new List<string> { };

    public BaseControllerTests(WebApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task TestCreateModel()
    {
        // Arrange
        var client = _factory.CreateClient();
        var newModel = new TModel
        {
            // Here normally I would initialize the properties
        };

        // Act
        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/[controller]", newModel);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var model = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<TModel>();

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
        // Here I would normally assert the properties of the model

        // Add model id to the list to delete later
        _modelIds.Add(model.Id);
    }
}
```

If I have different models like this:

```
Copy code
public class BaseModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}

public class ProductModel : BaseModel
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}

public class UserModel : BaseModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to implement a generic xUnit test? Or is it a stupid idea?

Comment: It sounds like a great idea. Is your problem about how to initialize and assert the properties, or are you facing some other problem? Another design would be to make a [Theory] method taking a ``Type`` parameter along with a parameter with information about what initial values to use. Somewhere you're going to have to define them.

Comment: I would recommend against. Unit tests are meant to be quite specific and sometimes over generalising isn't the best way forward. The last line "_modelIds.Add()" should give you an indication on why this is bad. You would have to guarantee an order of unit tests for this to work and therefore making your unit tests depend on each other.

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins Yes my problem is about how to initialize and assert the properties for each model (because they will have different properties). I will take a look on the [Theory] method. Thank you

Comment: @scottdavidwalker the last line is for the Dispose method to clean up database after testing. The goal for all unit test is that they will run independend of each other. I just don't want to write the same lines again and again for each model to test the basic crud actions as only the model (and it's properties) will change in this case.

Comment: Would it not dispose automatically after the test was done? objects are destroyed and recreated after every test with XUnit (unless you're using a class fixture)

Comment: Never mind, just seen you're using a class fixutre

Comment: Could your classes override the Equals() method to do a member-by-member comparison? Then you could ``Assert.Equals(newModel, model)``